# Mysql update 6 rows based on 1 row

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a wordpress database table called "wp_postmeta"

It looks like this (simplified)

```
meta_id     post_id meta_key        meta_value
1           5       _price          -
2           5       _visibility     -
3           5       _stock          -
4           5       _stock_status   -
5           5       _sale_price     -
6           5       _regular_price  -
7           5       _sku            REALSKU
```

I need to update all _price, _visibility, _stock, _stock_status, _sale_price, _regular_price based on meta_value of _sku

I tried this, but cannot add another meta_values for update, so it update only _price based on sku:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta a
JOIN wp_postmeta b  ON a.post_id = b.post_id
AND b.meta_key = '_sku'
AND b.meta_value LIKE 'RELASKU'

SET a.meta_value = '5'
WHERE a.meta_key = '_price'
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could achieve what you need with a CASE statement, such as:

```
SET a.meta_value = CASE a.meta_key
    WHEN '_price' THEN '5'
    WHEN '_visibility' THEN '6'
    ELSE a.meta_value
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case`:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta a JOIN
       wp_postmeta b 
       ON a.post_id = b.post_id AND
          b.meta_key = '_sku' AND
          b.meta_value LIKE 'RELASKU'
     SET a.meta_value = (CASE WHEN a.meta_key = '_price' THEN '5'
                              WHEN a.meta_key = '_visibility' . . .
                              ELSE a.meta_value
                         END)
WHERE a.meta_key IN ('_price', '_visibility', . . . );
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written query for you. I hope it will resolve your problem :

**Query**

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta a
       JOIN
     wp_postmeta b ON a.post_id = b.post_id
        AND b.meta_key = '_sku'
        AND b.meta_value LIKE 'RELASKU' 
SET 
    a.meta_value = 
    IFNULL(( CASE 
        WHEN a.meta_key = '_price' THEN  '13.5'
        WHEN a.meta_key = '_visibility' THEN  'None'
        WHEN a.meta_key = '_stock' THEN  '12'
        WHEN a.meta_key = '_stock_status' THEN  'Available'
        WHEN a.meta_key = '_sale_price' THEN  '12.5'
        WHEN a.meta_key = '_regular_price' THEN  '13.0'
     END),a.meta_value);
```

Comment: Replace `LEFT JOIN` with `JOIN`